# Design a system which consume data from different type of web services like SOAP and REST

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

If I want to design a system/application which takes data preferably through web services from different other application which have exposed the API in different type of web service like SOAP based and REST based. What should be the best approach to deal with such situation where I am getting slightly more or less fields apart from the mandatory fields which is required in my application to run my algorithm.

Comment: What kind of application do you want to build? web service? android? desktop?

Comment: web based application

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: SPRING BOOT**

You can build a service to consume other services and process them using Spring boot.

- *Pros:* You can choose an archetype when building the app, lots of documentations. Easy to get started using the  https://start.spring.io/
- *Cons:* Very heavy, some configuration can be tricky.

**Option 2: SPARK**

If you want something more simple and basic I would recommend Spark (Don't confuse with Apache Spark) it is a very light web server framework. https://sparkjava.com/

- *Pros:* Light and simple, easy to get started.
- *Cons:* You need to implement all the external calls and database access if you need it too.

There are a lot of frameworks similar to these. Just by doing a google search "Web server frameworks for java" you can find very interesting articles.

If you want to know about different design patterns. You can find a good explanation of the main ones in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrT3AO8bVQY